# Conditionally disable warnings with qmake/gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, conditional-statements, compiler-warnings, qmake

I am involved with a software project written in Qt and built with qmake and gcc on Linux.  We have to link to a third-party library that is of fairly low quality and spews tons of warnings.  I would like to use -W -Wall on our source code, but pass -w to the nasty third-party library to keep the console free of noise and clutter so we can focus on our code quality.

In qmake, is there a way to conditionally add CFLAGS/CXXFLAGS to certain files and libraries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jonathan, I think the problem is where your source files are including header files from 3rd party libraries, and you want to switch off the warnings for the latter.

Kevin, i think you can use pragmas to control warnings : [gcc diagnostic pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.3/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas)

You could add these before and after any #includes for 3rd party libs.

Comment: Correct, the warnings come from the third-party headers.  I will look into pragmas, but is there a way I can inject them only into the third-party headers, or will I have to edit their headers?

Comment: You could introduce header wrappers for the third party headers. One brute-force approach would be to put any include for a third party header into a single header, then  your app just includes that header where necessary. E.g. if your App uses library Zed then create a zed.h header which includes all Zed headers. Then you can add the pragmas to zed.h.
Or just go through your code and surround each #include <zed/some_header.h> with pragmas.

Answer (score 3):

What if you include your library using -isystem.

In the project file e.g.:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -isystem /usr/local/boost_1_44_0
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you'd build the third-party library in a separate directory from your own code, so you would have a different makefile for it, so you could put a different set of flags for that compilation.

If you've mixed the third-party library code with your own code, you have set yourself up for a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin,

```
qmake CONFIG+=debug QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON=-w QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_ON=-w
```

should do 
(use CONFIG+=release if you wish...)

Comment: This just adds -w globally, not conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

As Martin wrote adding the include directory via

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -isystem ...
```

suppresses warnings just in the respective headers. No need to disable warnings for any source files of your project (or even project-wide) or mess with #pragmas or wrappers files.

Note that if you're using QtCreator you'll still (i.e. additionally) want add the directory to `INCLUDEPATH` so the indexer picks up the headers.